# TDD - How to test simple get list

Tags: tdd

I'm really confused here. Let's say my user story looks like this.

"A user must be able to look at the stats of every player in the league so that he can scout 
properly."

Maybe the user story is bad but still how am I supposed to TDD that? I'm I supposed to test against the property I am expecting? I am really lost here and would appreciate your point of view.

EDIT: I am fairly new to TDD but I get the basic and have done a few katas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing isn't really fine-grained enough to TDD in code, but you can break it down.

First of all, how are they going to be presented with the information they need to do the search? Are they going to see all the stats? Search for a player? Search for a particular stat? This gives you finer-grained behavior, and now you can start thinking about the interface that the user will use. Think of just one example of something the user does - maybe searching for a player, perhaps visiting the first page, etc. Make it something interesting but simple.

Once you know what this part of the UI will look like, you can code it. (You *could* TDD it but normally the interface changes quite a bit and UI automation is hard, so most people don't TDD UIs).

The UI will want to get some information from somewhere, and pass some information back. You'll find yourself thinking about a collaborating class - probably a controller or a presenter - which will help the UI. In turn, that controller will want to control the interactions between some other classes - the UI itself, the repository for player stats, security, validation, etc. This is the first class you'll write tests for.

You can now start writing the test for the controller. You already know how the UI is going to use it. Just write an example of how another class might be able to use the controller in the same way, what kind of information the controller needs, and what outcome you get when you use it.

Of course, you don't have any other classes yet, and the controller might need them. Use interfaces for the roles that those classes will play, dependency-inject them, and mock or stub them out in your test.

At some point the controller will be ready to do something, but you still can't run the application because you haven't finished coding the collaborating classes - they're still just interfaces. Do the same thing again for them - pretend you're the controller, using them, and if they need any other classes, mock or stub them out.

Eventually you won't have any classes to mock or stub, and the first scenario in the user interface will run. If you want to get faster feedback, at any point you can just hard-code some data so that the UI runs and you can see what it looks like.

Doing it this way is called *outside-in*, and is related to BDD, a slightly different way of thinking about TDD. I hope that [this page](http://lizkeogh.com/behaviour-driven-development/) might help you.

Comment: Ok I get it, I should start from my controller all the way to the bottom.... but the point is I am in fact creating a DLL only, there will be no interfaces in what I am suppose to do, just a plain API. So I guess that means that my user stories need to be more specific then what they are at the moment! Tx for your input.

Comment: If you're creating a library, I recommend creating a really simple mock app to use the library as a way of testing it. For instance, I created a fake pet shop to test my UI automation tool, and the API for JBehave was originally written by using it for Conway's Game of Life. *Your* user interface will then be the API itself, and you'll probably want to TDD it. It's just that your user is another system, rather than a human being. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You have it essentially correct. You didn't state whether you have prior experience with unit testing or TDD, so I don't know how much of what follows is going to be a retread for you.

You start out by writing a test that you know is going to fail. In the example you provided, let's say your `Player` class doesn't have a `Stats` field. So you write a test to ensure that you can access the `Stats` field. It's going to fail; it might not even build, because you're referencing a field that doesn't exist yet. Then you add the field. The test passes. Then the cycle begins again.

Let's say that you have a specific stat that's calculated based off of other stats. You write a failing test checking for the presence of that stat before you've written the logic to even calculate it. It will fail. You implement the logic to generate the stat. The test passes. Repeat.

Try checking out these [TDD kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) by Roy Osherove, who wrote the fantastic book *The Art of Unit Testing*.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am fairly new to TDD but what if I just need to list my users (no stats) what would my test look like? Should I just check if count >0 on some mocked item returning a few users?

Comment: I don't know what language you're writing in, but I would test that the *source* of your users is returning the appropriate users given your conditions. Assuming your data source is a database, I'd create a mock with a handful of users (let's say 3, so your expected value is 3). Then, through your user-retrieval class, you make sure that when you call the GetAllUsers() method, it returns a data structure with a count == 3.

Comment: Thats what I had in mind but didn't know if it was good idea or not. tx. I also just ordered the book! :)

Answer (score 2):

From here you need to create tasks that describe the actual steps a little better.  Each task generally should not take more tahn 12 hours to complete.  For example, a task could be, "Add an RPI to column to the List Players page."  From here, you have something that you can start writing tests for.

Assuming that you use some MVC framework, you can write a test that checks whether or not your model can report RPI.  Then, you can write a test to make sure that your controller is supplying the RPI to the view.  And finally, you can write a test to make sure that your view will display the RPI when it is supplied.

In Rails, I would add a known RPI to a test database on a known player before the actual test runs.  Then, I could write a unit test that looks like this:

```
known_player.rpi.should == 0.6902
```

All of those tests will fail.  Then, as you start to implement each actual feature, you should run your tests again and watch as they start to pass.

Comment: So I should test against all the properties of my known object?

Comment: Ya, I would write one test that that looks at all the properties of you object and makes sure that you can properly retrieve them from the database or wherever you get them.  It's a small test and simple to write.  It depends on your language and testing framework.  Rails makes this easy, but at work, I don't have the luxury of using databases that I can populate for tests. So, I have to get creative.  We're working on that.